# Finding basis for $\operatorname{Im} T$ using $[T]_{C}^{B}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $T : V \to W$ is a linear map, $B=(b_1, \dots , b_n)$ - basis for $V$ and $C=(c_1, \dots , c_m)$ basis for $W$. Now, I want to find a basis for $\operatorname{Im} T$. Here's a way to do this according to my book:

> On the one hand, we know that $\operatorname{Im} T=\operatorname{span} \{ T(b_1), \dots , T(b_n) \}$.
>
> On the other hand, the column space $L$ of $[T]_{C}^{B}$ (matrix
>   representing the linear map with respect to the bases $B$ and $C$) is
>   $L=\operatorname{span} \{ [T(b_1)]_C , \dots , [T(b_n)]_C\} $. Then,
>   by applying Gaussian elimination on the transpose of $[T]_{C}^{B}$ we
>   get row echelon form from which we can obtain basis for $L$ (we'll
>   denote it as $l_1, \dots , l_k$). Then, by converting each coordinate
>   vector from $l_1, \dots , l_k$ to vectors in $W$ we obtain the basis
>   for $\operatorname{Im} T$.

Now I don't understand the last sentence. By "converting from coordinate vectors to vectors" they mean applying the inverse of $S(w)=[w]_C$ on the vectors $l_1, \dots , l_k$. That is, we apply the linear map $S^{-1} : F^m \to W$. $S^{-1}$ is an isomorphism because $S$ is an isomorphism, and thus we have a correspondence between the bases of $F^m$ and $W$. That is, the image of any basis of $F^m$ is a basis of $W$. However, $\{ l_1, \dots , l_k \}$  need not be a basis for $F^m$, because $k \leq m$. The same with $S^{-1} (l_1) , \dots , S^{-1} (l_k)$ which is not necessarily a basis for $W$. In fact, $G=\operatorname{span} \{l_1, \dots, l_k \} \subseteq F^m$ and $U=\operatorname{span} \{S^{-1} (l_1) , \dots , S^{-1} (l_k)\} \subseteq W$. We probably can reduce the domain and the codomain of $S^{-1}$ to $G$ and $U$ respectively. But then for $S^{-1} : G \to U$ to be an isomorphism we must have $\dim G = \dim U$ in the first place. How can we be sure that this is the case?

In short - how do we know that by converting a basis for $L$ to vectors in $W$ we obtain a basis for $\operatorname{Im} T$?

Comment: "thus we have a correspondence between the bases of $F^m$ and $W$: remember that you are after a basis for $\mathrm{Im}(T)\subseteq W$, not a basis for $W$!

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen - thank you for your response. Indeed, I acknowledge that. But that's the point - how can we be sure that $S^{-1} : F^m \to \operatorname{Im} T$ is an isomorphism if we can't be sure about $\dim \operatorname{Im} T$ (because the whole point of this is finding the basis for $\operatorname{Im} T$)? Is this whole procedure based on the fact that $\dim \operatorname{Im} T = \operatorname{rank} ([T]_{C}^{B})$?

Comment: $S^{-1}$ is an isomorphism $F^m\to W$, but it is **not** an isomorphism $F^m \to \operatorname{Im} T$. It is not even a map between those sets.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen - sorry, my mistake. I meant $S^{-1} : G \to \operatorname{Im} T$ where $G$ is the vector space spanned by the columns of $[T]_{C}^{B}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making too much problems about something basically quite simple. The map $S:W\to F^m$ expresses vectors in coordinates with respect to the ordered basis $C$; it is the inverse of the map $S^{-1}:F^m\to W$ that forms linear combinations of the vector of$~C$ with the given coefficients, explicitly $S^{-1}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=a_1c_1+\cdots+a_nc_n$. It is actually more natural to start with the latter map (which exists independently of the fact that $C$ is a basis), and then to say that it is invertible because $C$ is a basis, and $S$ is its inverse map. They are a pair of mutually inverse isomorphisms between $W$ and $F^m$.

Now applying $S^{-1}$ to any linearly independent set $E$ of vectors in $F^m$, one obtains a set $S^{-1}(E)$ of vectors in $W$ that is linearly independent; the image $\def\sp{\operatorname{span}}S^{-1}(\sp(E))$ of the subspace for which $E$ is a basis equals $\sp(S^{-1}(E))$, and $S^{-1}(E)$ is a basis of the latter subspace. That is because $S^{-1}:F^m\to W$ is an isomorphism. All of this is quite general, and just means the things computed in coordinates (in $F^n$) faithfully reflect what is going on in the vector space$~W$.

In your example you start with a subspace $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ of $W$, for which $T(b_1),\ldots,T(b_n)$ form a spanning set. In order to find a *basis* for the subspace, one applies $S$ to each vector to get into coordinates $(F^n)$, then uses some numeric technique to find a basis of the subspace they span in $F^n$ (in the example the technique is reduction to column echelon form using Gaussian elimination), and finally one applies $S^{-1}$ to the result to get the basis of $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ that one was after. The final step is what I detailed in the second paragraph, with $E$ equal to the set of linearly independent columns in the column echelon form.

The passages between $W$ and $F^n$ are themselves painless, and usually not commented upon a lot: one could just say the basis was found by applying reduction to column echelon form to the spanning set of $\operatorname{Im}(T)$, after passing to coordinates with respect to$~C$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think the important part is that $S^{-1} (\operatorname{span}(E))=\operatorname{span}(S^{-1}(E))$ - I didn't know that. Is it true because $[\beta_1 v_1 + \dots + \beta_n v_n]_B=\beta_1 [v_1]_B + \dots + \beta_n [v_n]_B $ (which is one of the reasons for $S$ being an isomorphism)? The reason for all the confusion was that I only saw proofs for correspondence between bases for **domain** and the **codomain** of $S$, and not for some **subspace** of domain/codomain spanned by some subset $E$.

Comment: actually, $T (\operatorname{span}(E))=\operatorname{span}(T(E))$ holds for any linear transformation and not just for isomorphisms. Am I correct?

Comment: @user217919: Correct. Because linear maps preserve linear combinations (which define the span).

Comment: Ok. So I think the question is why in this case $\operatorname{span}(S^{-1} (E))=\operatorname{Im} T$.

Comment: Well, because $E$ was computed from $S(\{T(b_1),\ldots,T(b_n)\})$ so as to be basis for the subspace they span, which subspace is $S(\operatorname{Im}(T))$. From $\sp(E)=S(\operatorname{Im}(T))$ one gets $S^{-1}(\sp(E))=\operatorname{Im}(T)$, while also $S^{-1}(\sp(E))=\sp(S^{-1}(E))$.

Comment: this is a perfect explanation. Thank you for your patience and have a good day.